# What is the R equivalent of Matlab's `sphere()` function

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to replicate some Matlab code in R and I have been looking around for an R equivalent of Matlab's `sphere()` function.

For reference the `sphere()` function documentation is [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sphere.html).

For clarification, I am interested in the actual assignment properties of `sphere()`. Namely I am interested in knowing how to write

```matlab
[X,Y,Z]=sphere(200)
```

In R.

Comment: `?rgl::spheres3d` or `rgl::ellipse3d` perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```r
library(geometry)
sphere <- function(n) {
   dd <- expand.grid(theta = seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = n+1)[-1],
                     phi = seq(-pi, pi, length.out = n+1)[-1])
   sph2cart(dd$theta, dd$phi, r = 1)
}
```

Really you don't need the `geometry` package either, as the payload of `geometry::sphere2cart` is just

```r
x <- r * cos(phi) * cos(theta)
y <- r * cos(phi) * sin(theta)
z <- r * sin(phi)
```

The other 20-odd lines of code are argument-processing and error-checking.  So you could put together your own self-contained function using just `expand.grid` and the three lines of geometry.

Take 2: return a list of 3, (n+1 x n+1) matrices.

```r
sphere <- function(n) {
   dd <- expand.grid(theta = seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = n+1),
                     phi = seq(-pi, pi, length.out = n+1))
   with(dd, 
        list(x = matrix(cos(phi) * cos(theta), n+1),
             y = matrix(cos(phi) * sin(theta), n+1),
             z = matrix(sin(phi), n+1))
        )
}
```

This will return a list of matrices with names x, y, z, not assign values to variables in the calling environment ... that's difficult/non-idiomatic in R.

Comment: The dimension of the function does not seem to match that of `sphere`. When I run `size(sphere(200));` I get 201x201 but this does not return the same dimensions.

Comment: does `sphere()` include repeated values, in other words if there are 201 values of the computed x variable, do they include two values of `x=0`? In any case a small tweak to the `seq()` statement above this will fix it. If there *are* repeated values then the solution is slightly simplified from what I wrote, i.e. `seq(..., length.out = n+1)` (i.e. no `[-1]`)

Comment: Just looking at the `expand.grid` output I notice that the dimensions are `3 x 40401` for` `sphere(200)`. Additionally to use `sph2cart()` an apply function is required.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "an apply function is required". In any case, see edits.

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, I'd use `phi = seq(-pi/2, pi/2, length.out = n+1)` to reduce overlapping. And maybe `theta = seq(-pi, pi, length.out = n+1)` for standard convention. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just trying to come up with a quick and dirty solution that matched the OP's needs.

Answer (score 2):

This looks fairly similar to `spheresurf3D` from the `plot3D` package

```r
library(plot3D)

spheresurf3D(bty = "b", ticktype = "detailed", phi = 30, theta = 135,
             shade = 0.5, border = "black", col = jet.col()[1:75])
```

[image]

Comment: While that visually satisfies what I want, I am more interested in getting the X, Y and Z coordinates of `sphere()` in vector form. Something like `[X,Y,Z]=sphere(200)`